# Store user messages

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it secure to store user chat messages in database as plain text?

*And another question*: Where to store page content - in database or in files? Wordpress holds blog entries in database, but it takes 25 requests to database to display a page, so website perfomance decreases.

Comment: how did you know it is 25 requests to show a page ?

Comment: @Shyju it depends on theme you choose http://www.cravingtech.com/reduce-wordpress-cpu-usage-3-reduce-your-database-queries.html

Comment: Well, as long as they're not chatting about their passwords or their SINs or their credit card numbers... why not?

Comment: Yea. Page content and theme items are different. Theme items are like a fancy addons. If you want many of those. You should be able to face it by allowing that many DB call. So it is your call, the more you want, the more you have to face it.

Comment: @Palladium what if their private messages leaked?

Comment: Well, why would they chat about confidential information on a publicly available chatroom which purposefully logs all their conversations anyway? Considering the nature of the application (that it's a chatroom), where it is (on the Internet, where it is public),  and what it does (stores copies of chats), I'm tempted to just say that if someone gets their information stolen, it's their own fault for being stupid enough to disclose it there in the first place.

Comment: @Palladium: That's a pretty tough line to take.  Plenty of sensitive personal information is emailed about the place, where your metrics all hold true.  Sure, one could argue that any loss of data owing to compromise of the user's email host is the user's own fault for being stupid enough not to encrypt their emails, but I doubt the majority of users would see it in that way.  You seem to be implying that one should, for example, view the privacy of Gmail differently to that of Gtalk; or Hotmail vs MSN Messenger; or Facebook email vs Facebook chat.

Comment: @Palladium I mean the situation when 2 logged users talk privately. How to defend their messages in this case?

Comment: Again, I'm strongly of the opinion that no amount of foolproofing is useful against the most ingenious fools. Of course, you *can* encrypt user chat messages and that would definitely be *more* secure than plaintext, but 1) you have much bigger problems to take care of if they've breached your database, and 2) the cost-benefit analysis of encrypting those messages is highly debatable.

Comment: @eggyal Not even. I'm saying we should view the privacy of all emails as the same as chats (that is, not at all). There's also the fact that the companies you listed have much more resources in securing their sites than what the OP is working on (presumably). Really, if you're transmitting sensitive information, you should not be looking at email or chats.

Comment: @Palladium Would you post conclusion from this comments as an answer to mark question completed?

Comment: @Palladium: As true as that may be from a theoretical standpoint, it doesn't change the fact that email is today used for transmitting all manner of personal and sensitive information.  Therefore users (perhaps wrongly, but nevertheless they do) have an *expectation* of a certain level of protection against straightforward compromise.  To tell them that they are stupid when their data is lost from your system yet their friends' is safer on your competitors' system perhaps won't go down so well in practice.

Comment: @eggyal Good point. However, I believe it just as likely that someone would read over someone else's shoulder to see the private information they decided to (unwisely) post on a chat server as someone would hack into the server (I assume the OP has placed proper security measures to prevent that) to ransack the chats for private information (which might not even be there). And really, anyone with expectations of a *chat* system on wordpress protecting their information is clearly expecting too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of comments:

- Considering the nature of the application (a chatroom on the Internet), I feel that saving the chats as plain text is acceptable assuming that the users do not chat about private/sensitive/confidential information.
- The above assumption can be made given some faith and optimism in the human race (i.e.: that it is smart enough to realize that a chatroom or a PM session is not the time or place to give out passwords, SINs, credit card numbers, etc.).
- Concerning the, well... concerns surrounding the situation in which a person betrays the above assumption, I am of the belief that no amount of foolproofing is enough for the most ingenious fool. While encrypting the chat is most definitely *more* secure than not, the cost of encrypting each and every chat as opposed to the applicability of the added benefit to chats (that is, none whatsoever unless the chat contains sensitive information, which is a rare case at best) provides little incentive to encrypt those chats. A much simpler solution would be to simply disclaim any responsibility for private information leaked from the chats.
- One last tidbit on handling sensitive information (this one's for Internet users everywhere): don't do it through email, chat, or any unsecured connection. Try as much as possible to avoid putting sensitive information where it will be logged, unless you have absolute confidence the logs won't be breached.

Comment: Great. Last question: how users feel about website owner's ability to read their messages?

Comment: @riwette Well, if I was a user I would personally prefer that the owners don't read my messages unless there is clear and sufficient reason for them to want to (if they suspect that my messages contain spam, hacking attempts, etc.). So the ability should not be intrinsically there, but I wouldn't mind if my chats were ultimately somehow accessible to the owner. (Again, this is part of why you might want a disclaimer.)

Comment: Question is now completed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Separate questions really ought to be posted as separate questions...

And neither question is sufficiently well-defined to give anything but the broadest of answers...

But here we go:

1. Whether or not something is "secure" depends on your threat model (i.e. your definition of "secure").  But what alternatives are available to you?  If you encrypt the messages, where will you store the decryption key?
2. Where to store data depends on the structure of such data and how you intend for it to be used.  If it is "static" and will always be queried in predictable ways, a filesystem may provide sufficient structure for good performance; however, if the data is "dynamic" (i.e. your application will modify it), then a database may offer greater flexibility or better performance.  As with most problems in computing, the design decision you take is a trade-off for which the best answer will depend on your own requirements (and indeed, your metric of what is "best").

Answer (score 1):

As long as you  keep your database credentials safe with you, It is fine to keep them in database. I do not see any reason to keep them encrypted.

What kind of page content are you talking about ? If it is a CMS kinds stuff, If you keep page contents as Pages, How many pages you are going to keep. God !!!!

You should use a database to keep such things. It makes things easier to update the content in the future etc. And you do not need to worry about Querying your database. Find out items which are not being updated frequently and cache it. when your page needs those contents , get it from the cache layer instead of the DB tables.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it secure to store user chat messages in database as plain text?

Depends on how sensible is the information and how secure is the database itself. Example: Can the database be accessed from outside or only from localhost? However if you feel that you need an extra layer of security, then it doesn't hurt to use some simple way of obfuscation.

---

> Where to store html page content - in database or in files?

Most of the times, accessing files is quicker than accessing the Database.

Database should be used to store/access information in a structured way, enabling elaborated searches, data changes, etc... Static HTML is probably better to save in the filesystem. However, sometimes it might be best to store html content in the database.
Examples:

Storing in database makes it easier to change database information from an admin page, than changing the file system (also, it's safer). So for dynamically created pages, or in a CMS (such as Drupal or Wordpress) it might be best to store content and "layouts" in the database.

Forum posts contain "content" as well as markup (styling). You don't usually separate one from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Database storage ends in files too. Compression is in use - less memory for saving in the end.

Comment: One could just as easily say that a filesystem is a database.  This argument gets very blurry and doesn't really add much.  I also think this ought to have been a comment rather than an answer.